# Using Camera with Visual Recognition IBM Watson in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ibm-watson

To start off im really new  to this, I have recently used vuforia with unity for ar applications and such.

Now to the main thing ,
what i am trying to do is use camera of mobile app to take a pic and use it later for visual recognition
can anyone help with this.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Services.VisualRecognition.v3;
using IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Logging;
using IBM.Watson.DeveloperCloud.Utilities;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class neww : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    private string _apikey = "<api-key>";
    private string _url = "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-
recognition/api";

    private VisualRecognition _visualRecognition;
    private string _visualRecognitionVersionDate = "2016-05-20";
    private bool _classifyGetTested = false;
    private bool _classifyPostTested = false;
    private string _imageURL = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/Official_portrait_of_Barack_Obama.jpg";
    Log.Debug("ExampleVisualRecognition", "Attempting to get classify via URL");
    if (!_visualRecognition.Classify(OnClassifyGet, _imageURL))
        Log.Debug("ExampleVisualRecognition", "Classify image failed!");
}
private void OnClassifyGet(ClassifyTopLevelMultiple classify, string data)
{
    Log.Debug("ExampleVisualRecognition", "VisualRecognition - ClassifyGet Response: {0}", data);
    _classifyGetTested = true;

}

private void OnClassifyPost(ClassifyTopLevelMultiple classify, string data)
{
    Log.Debug("ExampleVisualRecognition", "VisualRecognition - ClassifyPost Response: {0}", data);
    _classifyPostTested = true;
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Stack Overflow is not a free coding service. Show your specific problem, and where you stuck with your code and we can help. Cheers.

Comment: Am extremely sorry! will send

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT: You should never post your service credentials in public. Please remove your apikey from here and delete the credentials from the service. You can create new credentials for the service instance.**

You should be able to access the device camera using WebCamTexture.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html

There is an overload method to Classify that takes bytearray data. The signature looks like

```
bool Classify(OnClassify callback, byte[] imageData, string[] owners = default(string[]), string[] classifierIDs = default(string[]), float threshold = default(float), string acceptLanguage = "en", string customData = default(string));
```

You can try something like this (not tested)

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public WebCamTexture webcamTexture;
    public Color32[] data;
    private string _apikey = "<api>";
    private string _url = "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api";

    private VisualRecognition _visualRecognition;
    private string _visualRecognitionVersionDate = "2016-05-20";

    void Start() 
    {
        //  Instantiate Visual Recognition service
        Credential credential = new Credential(_apikey, _url);
        _visualRecognition = new VisualRecognition();
        _visualRecognition.VersionDate = _visualRecognitionVersionDate;

        //  Init the WebCamTexture and byte data
        webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
        webcamTexture.Play();
        data = new Color32[webcamTexture.width * webcamTexture.height];

        //  Send data to service
        if (!_visualRecognition.Classify(OnClassify, data))
            Log.Debug("ExampleVisualRecognition", "Classify image failed!");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //  Get bytearray data from webcam every frame
        webcamTexture.GetPixels32(data);
    }

    private void OnClassify(ClassifyTopLevelMultiple classify, string data)
    {
        //  Print classify response
        Log.Debug("Webcam example", "response: {0}", data);
    }
}
```